# Why does assigning a MySQL pool to a member variable revert to undefined when a member function is called?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to create one connection pool that every query will use. To do so, I've created a very simple class that assigns the connection pool to a member variable. The member variable is correctly set in the constructor, but when a member function is called that references the pool member variable, pool is null.

NOTE: I'm intentionally withholding credentials. Rest assured that it's correct on my end. :)

```
// Promise wrapper for MySQL driver
class Database {
    constructor( connectionLimit = 10 ){
        this.pool = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit : connectionLimit,
            host            : 'XXX',
            user            : 'XXX',
            password        : 'XXX',
            database        : 'XXX'
        });

        console.log( this.pool ) // No problem!
    }

    query( sql, params ){
        console.log( this.pool ) //UNDEFINED!!!!

        // Irrelevant code removed
    }
}
```

Now, if I define pool on the module level instead of in the class constructor, everything works as expected.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'XXX',
    user            : 'XXX',
    password        : "XXX",
    database        : 'XXX'
});

// Promise wrapper for MySQL driver
class Database {
    constructor( connectionLimit = 10 ){
        console.log( this.pool ) // No problem!
    }

    query( sql, params ){
        console.log( this.pool ) // No problem!
        
        // Irrelevant code removed
    }
}
```

In the first example, I expect `this.pool` to refernce the pool created in the constructor regardless of which member function is called. The second example does exactly what I would expect it to do.

This class is being used in an express API application. I'm creating an instance of Database, and then assigning a reference to the query method to the req object.

```
const db = new Database();
app.use( ( req, res, next ) => {
    req.query = db.query // Pretty sure I'm borking up the context here
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using `.query`, in the different module?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Upon closer examination, I'm certain that you found my issue. I'm borking up the context when I assign a reference to the query method to the req object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
req.query = db.query
```

When `req.query` gets used later, it'll probably look something like:

```
req.query(parameters)
```

When the internal code calls `callback`, it calls it with the calling context of `req`, or with no calling context at all, if put into a standalone variable first; it's not called as a property of the object `db` object. So when the function is invoked, the `this` inside the callback does not refer to a particular database instance.

Another way to solve your problem without a module variable would be to pass a callback *which itself calls* `.query` with the proper calling context:

```
req.query = (...args) => db.query(...args);
```